# What is the significance of the Frasier episode title 'Agents in America part III'?

Tags: title, frasier

There weren't parts one or two, but this title clearly has meaning. Perhaps they were classified, like Leonard parts 1-5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like a lot of other shows (like the Simpsons, for instance), [Frasier's episode titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Frasier_episodes) were sometimes puns or allusions to movies, shows, books and other pop culture references. This episode's title, [according to TV.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/frasier/agents-in-america-part-iii-16998/), is **alluding to Tony Kushner's famous play [Angels in America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_in_America:_A_Gay_Fantasia_on_National_Themes)**, which 2 parts premiered separately in 1991 and 1992 (the episode is from 1995):

> Episode Title: Agents in America, Part III
>   A reference to the two-part play Angels in America (hence the "Part III" in the title).

It's also worth noting that it's possibly 'Part III' as [**this is the 3rd episode with Frasier's agent Bebe**](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0014280/filmoseries#tt0106004) (follwing *Selling Out* and *And the Whimper Is...*). I don't think there's much of a connection between the plot of this episode and *Angels in America* (maybe Bebe's machinations could be compared to Roy Cohn's shady dealings, but that's a stretch), so it's probably just a pun and nothing more.